# Grouping the result set based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, date-arithmetic, lateral-join

I am calculating Age of a user based on his date of birth.

```
select UserId, (Convert(int,Convert(char(8),GETDATE(),112))-Convert(char(8),[DateOfBirth],112))/10000 AS [Age] FROM dbo.[User]
```

This gives me the `UserId` and his age.

Now I want to group this result.

How many users are in 30's, How many users in 40's and how many users in their 50's.. need the count of users with their age groups

If the user is > 0 and less than 30 he should be grouped to 20's

If the user is >= 30 and < 40 then he should be added to 30's list, same with 40's and 50's

Can this be achieved without creating any temp table?

Comment: Sub-query, cte... give it a go.

Comment: @DaleK i am comfortable with subqueries, can you help with a sample so that i can customize it according to my requirement.. If the user is > 0 and less than 30 he should be grouped to 20's

Comment: @DaleK I tried Rounding the above query but in that case i cannot add user to 20's group if he is less than 10 years. in my case i need to add user to 20's if he is even 1 year old

Comment: Sub-query + sum(case when ...) give it a go and see how you get on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will get you what you want.

Anything < 30 will be placed in the '20' group.
Anything >= 50 will be placed in the '50' group.

If they are 30-39 or 40-49, they will be placed in their appropriate decade group.

```sql
SELECT y.AgeDecade, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.[User] u
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT Age = (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) - CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), u.DateOfBirth, 112))) / 10000) x
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT AgeDecade = CASE
                                        WHEN x.Age <= 29 THEN 20
                                        WHEN x.Age BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN 30
                                        WHEN x.Age BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN 40
                                        WHEN x.Age >= 50 THEN 50
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END
    ) y
GROUP BY y.AgeDecade
```

Placing the logic into `CROSS APPLY` makes it easier to reuse the logic within the same query, this way you can use it in SELECT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, WHERE, etc, without having to duplicate it. This could also be done using a cte, but in this scenario, this is my preference.

---

### Update:

You asked in the comments how it would be possible to show a count of 0 when no people exist for an age group. In most cases the answer is simple, `LEFT JOIN`. As with everything, there's always more than one way to bake a cake.

Here are a couple ways you can do it:

The simple left join, take the query from my original answer, and just do a left join to a table. You could do this in a couple ways, CTE, temp table, table variable, sub-query, etc. The takeaway is, you need to isolate your User table somehow.

Simple Sub-query method, nothing fancy. Just stuck the whole query into a sub-query, then left joined it to our new lookup table.

```sql
DECLARE @AgeGroup TABLE (AgeGroupID tinyint NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @AgeGroup (AgeGroupID) VALUES (20),(30),(40),(50);

SELECT ag.AgeGroupID, TotalCount = COUNT(a.AgeDecade)
FROM @AgeGroup ag
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT y.AgeDecade
        FROM #User u
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT Age = (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) - CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), u.DateOfBirth, 112))) / 10000) x
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT AgeDecade = CASE
                                                WHEN x.Age <= 29 THEN 20
                                                WHEN x.Age BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN 30
                                                WHEN x.Age BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN 40
                                                WHEN x.Age >= 50 THEN 50
                                                ELSE NULL
                                            END
            ) y
    ) a ON a.AgeDecade = ag.AgeGroupID
GROUP BY ag.AgeGroupID;
```

This would be the exact same thing as using a cte:

```sql
DECLARE @AgeGroup TABLE (AgeGroupID tinyint NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @AgeGroup (AgeGroupID) VALUES (20),(30),(40),(50);

WITH cte_Users AS (
    SELECT y.AgeDecade
    FROM #User u
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT Age = (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) - CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), u.DateOfBirth, 112))) / 10000) x
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT AgeDecade = CASE
                                            WHEN x.Age <= 29 THEN 20
                                            WHEN x.Age BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN 30
                                            WHEN x.Age BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN 40
                                            WHEN x.Age >= 50 THEN 50
                                            ELSE NULL
                                        END
        ) y
)
SELECT ag.AgeGroupID, TotalCount = COUNT(a.AgeDecade)
FROM @AgeGroup ag
    LEFT JOIN cte_Users a ON a.AgeDecade = ag.AgeGroupID
GROUP BY ag.AgeGroupID;
```

Choosing between the two is purely preference. There's no performance gain to using a CTE here.

---

### Bonus:

If you wanted to table drive your groups and also have 0 counts, you could do something like this...though I will warn you to be careful using APPLY operators because they can be tricky with performance sometimes.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#User','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #User; --SELECT * FROM #User
WITH c1 AS (SELECT x.x FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(x))       -- 10
    , c2(x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM c1 x CROSS JOIN c1 y)                                     -- 10 * 10
SELECT UserID = IDENTITY(int,1,1)
    , DateOfBirth = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()-(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*18500))
INTO #User
FROM c2 u;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AgeRange','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #AgeRange; --SELECT * FROM #AgeRange
CREATE TABLE #AgeRange (
    AgeRangeID  tinyint         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    RangeStart  tinyint         NOT NULL,
    RangeEnd    tinyint         NOT NULL,
    RangeLabel  varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO #AgeRange (RangeStart, RangeEnd, RangeLabel)
VALUES ( 0,  29, '< 29')
    ,  (30,  39, '30 - 39')
    ,  (40,  49, '40 - 49')
    ,  (50, 255, '50+');

-- Using an OUTER APPLY
SELECT ar.RangeLabel, COUNT(y.UserID)
FROM #AgeRange ar
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT u.UserID
        FROM #User u
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT Age = (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) - CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), u.DateOfBirth, 112))) / 10000) x
        WHERE x.Age BETWEEN ar.RangeStart AND ar.RangeEnd
    ) y
GROUP BY ar.RangeLabel, ar.RangeStart
ORDER BY ar.RangeStart;

-- Using a CTE
WITH cte_users AS (
    SELECT u.UserID
        , Age = (CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112)) - CONVERT(int, CONVERT(char(8), u.DateOfBirth, 112))) / 10000
    FROM #User u
)
SELECT ar.RangeLabel, COUNT(u.UserID)
FROM #AgeRange ar
    LEFT JOIN cte_users u ON u.Age BETWEEN ar.RangeStart AND ar.RangeEnd
GROUP BY ar.RangeStart, ar.RangeLabel
ORDER BY ar.RangeStart;
```

Comment: chad , Lets say if there are no users in Age group 30 i.e between 30-39 but i still want to display 30 age group but with value 0, how do i achieve that  ?

Comment: @adityaa I think the best way to do that, would be to create a table which contains all of the ranges you are interested in. And then, instead of hard coding `<= 29`, `BETWEEN 30 AND 39`, instead you would select from that table, and then `LEFT JOIN` dbo.User to it. This way, you can drive these groupings by table, and also configure labels and such. I'll put something together and add it as an answer to this post so you can see what I mean. I'll add another comment tagging you so you know when to check for the update.

Comment: @adityaa okay, examples added

Comment: @adityaa I gave you a few different ways to do things. You don't have to do them this way, play around with the code, learn how to use CTEs, table variables, temp tables, sub-queries, etc, and just find what you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with a length argument of `-1` and a non-zero function argument to truncate the value to "tens", and group by it:

```sql
SELECT   UserId, 
         Round((Convert(int,Convert(char(8),GETDATE(),112))-Convert(char(8),[DateOfBirth],112))/10000, -1, 1) AS [Rounded Age],
         Count(*)
FROM     dbo.[User]
GROUP BY Round((Convert(int,Convert(char(8),GETDATE(),112))-Convert(char(8),[DateOfBirth],112))/10000, -1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

this query should work with you

```
SELECT STR(ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) + 's' AS [Age Group], COUNT(UserId) AS Count
FROM dbo.User
GROUP BY STR(ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) + 's'
```

for your updated question

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) < 30 THEN '20s' 
       WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) >= 50 THEN '50s' 
       ELSE str(ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) + 's' 
    END AS [Age Group], COUNT(UserId) AS Count
FROM dbo.User
GROUP BY CASE 
       WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) < 30 THEN '20s' 
       WHEN (ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) >= 50 THEN '50s' 
       ELSE str(ROUND(DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()), - 1) - 10) + 's' 
    END
```

Comment: i have updated the question, If the user is > 0 and less than 30 he should be grouped to 20's... this case fails with ROUND, i have 4 groups 20's, 30's, 40's, 50's anything above 50 even 90 should be added to 50's group

Comment: you can use case to achieve that, give me 5 min and will send you the select statement

Comment: @adityaa the updated one is that you need

Answer (score 0):

I would start by putting the age computation in a lateral join, so it can easily be referred to. Then, if you want the age groups as rows, you can join a derived table that describes the intervals:

```
select v.age_group, count(*) as cnt_users
from dbo.[User] u
cross apply (values 
    ((convert(int, convert(char(8), getdate(),112)) - convert(char(8), u.[DateOfBirth], 112))/10000) 
) a(age)
inner join (values 
    ( 0, 30, '0-30'), 
    (30, 40, '30-40'), 
    (40, 50, '40-50'),
    (50, null, '50+')
) v(min_age, max_age, age_group) 
    on  a.age >= v.min_age
    and (a.age < v.max_age or v.max_age is null)
group by v.age_group
```

On the other hands, if you want the counts in columns, use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(case when a.age < 30 then 1 else 0 end) as age_0_30,
    sum(case when a.age >= 30 and a.age < 40 then 1 else 0 end) as age_30_40,
    sum(case when a.age >= 40 and a.age < 50 then 1 else 0 end) as age_40_50,
    sum(case when a.age >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as age_50
from dbo.[User] u
cross apply (values 
    ((convert(int, convert(char(8), getdate(),112)) - convert(char(8), [DateOfBirth], 112))/10000) 
) a(age)
```